# How to set specific query string value (or update if exists) without appending the value on click of a <a> tag?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update or set a given URL specific query string value on a click of an `<a>` element.

I managed to make it work by setting the URL:

```
<a id="my-link" href="http://example.com/">

$('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
    let url = this.getAttribute('href');
    let queryStringKey = 'someKey';
    let queryStringValue = encodeURIComponent(someDataObject);
    let url += `?${key}=${queryStringValue}`;
    e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href = url; 
});
```

But this only works on the first click because it keeps appending the query string.

What I tried was to then save the original URL, set the url using `e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href` and then set it back after the click, but it doesn't work, it just reads the original url instead of the updated one:

```
<a id="my-link" href="http://example.com/">

$('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
    let originalUrl = this.getAttribute('href');
    let queryStringKey = 'someKey';
    let queryStringValue = encodeURIComponent(someDataObject);
    let updatedUrl += originalUrl + `?${key}=${queryStringValue}`;
    e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href = updatedUrl; 
    this.href = originalUrl; // it then opens this URL instead of the updatedUrl
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL API

Note: use `new URL(this.href);` if you do not have a valid URL since
`new URL(this.getAttribute("href"))` will fail on `href="/"`

```js
$('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // to see the console
  let queryStringKey = 'someKey';
  let queryStringValue = { x: 2 };
  let url = new URL(this.href); 
  url.searchParams.set(queryStringKey, queryStringValue);
  this.href=url.toString();
  console.log(this.href)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="my-link" href="/">Click</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever the url get clicked Remove the additional key value to restore the original link :

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    let someDataObject = 'someDataObject';
    $('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // to see the console
      let url = this.getAttribute('href');
     
      let queryStringKey = 'someKey';
      let queryStringValue = encodeURIComponent(someDataObject);

      url = url.split('?'+queryStringKey)[0];
  
      url += `?${queryStringKey}=${queryStringValue}`;
      
      console.log(url);
      e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href = url; 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="my-link" href="http://example.com/">click me</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do so:

```
$('#my-link').on('click', function(e) {
    let url = this.getAttribute('href').split('?')[0]; // remove old query string
    let queryStringKey = 'someKey';
    let queryStringValue = encodeURIComponent('someValue');
    url += `?${queryStringKey}=${queryStringValue}`;
    e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href = url; 
});
```